# Converting an array of arrays into a class array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, class

I know that this is a basic question, but I'm new to Python and seem to be unable to find an answer for. Let's say I have a user in my database with fields: name, surname, age. I make a user class in Python:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, array):
        self.name = array[0]
        self.surname = array[1]
        self.age = array[2]
```

When I access my DB and call for the users I get the array of arrays.

```
def get_users():
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `users`")
    return cursor.fetchall() #returns [[],[],[],[]...]
```

What is the simplest way to make every array in the arrays into the class?

```
[User, User,User,User,...]
```

(so when I'm iterating threw the elements in for loop, I could call user.name instead of user[0]) Is there a function for that or should I just go threw every single one element in the array and convert it into a class object?

Comment: can you post the user data you are getting from db

Comment: It would be somewhere in the lines of: [ ["James","Jenkinson", 23],["Alice","Madison",25]....]

Comment: you iterate the resuts. for each element you create a new user `u = User( elem )` and add that to a list that then contains all your users. Maybe use a dict instead to add them to, if you got a unique identifier so you can look them up fast later.

Comment: Maybe have a look into orm mappers that do the task for you automagically: https://www.fullstackpython.com/object-relational-mappers-orms.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `map()`

```
res =  [ ["James","Jenkinson", 23],["Alice","Madison",25]]
x = list(map(User, res))
for user in x:
    print(user.name,user.surname, user.age)
```

**Output:**

```
James Jenkinson 23
Alice Madison 25
```